# jQuery position() misunderstanding?

Tags: jquery

jQuery `position()` :

> Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements, relative to the offset parent.

What does it means `offset Parent` ? [**I made a simple example - JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/IPAtUye/2/) where an `input` is under a `pre` tag so the position should be `const number` (because the distance between the `input` and the `pre` (which is its father)  is a **fixed** distance it never changes)

**But** it counts the `scroll`.

I guess I don't understand the meaning of offsetParent... Any help ?

[image]

Comment: Relative position from parent

Comment: @RoryPicko92 but the parent is the PRE tag. and the measurement between the input and the PRE  does not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**jsBin Demo**](http://jsbin.com/IPAtUye/4/edit)

You didn't give `position: relative` to the `pre` element.

See the documentation you've posted yourself:

> Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements, relative to the **offset parent**.

---

> Also see: [.offsetParent()](http://api.jquery.com/offsetParent/)
>
> **Description:** Get the closest ancestor element that is positioned.

An element is said to be positioned if it has a CSS position attribute of `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`

Comment: Hi. My question was about the offset Parent translation. where does it say in DOCS that some element should be relative or X ... ? its just say offsetParent. and Im trying to understnad who is the offset parent and what do they mean when they say offset Parent.

Comment: I repeat My question : where does it say that offsetParent is the absolute  / relative parent.... ?

Comment: The offset parent in most cases is the real parent, but when you use an absolute position the offset parent is the closest relatively position parent.

Comment: Was it so hard for the JQ team to write "the first absolute parent" ?

Comment: See this: [offsetParent](http://api.jquery.com/offsetParent/). This is a common-used term.

Comment: Great. Thank you :-). **they should put the link there , in the offset Docs**

Comment: Itay look at this : http://jsbin.com/IPAtUye/7/edit  , here I set position absolute to the scrolled div , and it seems that the position changes according to the **visible viewport**.....weired but nice.

Comment: Yeah, it return the distance from the positioned container top.